# table width automatically to page width

Tags: tables

I am new user of LaTeX. I would like to ask a question, is there any command that automatically set the width of table to page width. I am using following code to add tables.

Let us say for such small table, as mentioned below, I would like to increase its width automatically to the page width. The extra space should equally distributed to all columns. so that width get equal to page width.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
a & b & c \\ \hline
1 & 3 & 5 \\ \hline
2 & 4 & 6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Yes there are. See e.g. the tabularx package or the tabular* environment described in every introduction. But you shouldn't do it with a tabular as in your example. To much white space makes tabulars hard to read.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, this is possible, but before giving an adequate answer we need to know where the extra space (page width minus current width of the tabular) should go. Equally distributed to all columns?

Comment: As the commends show, we have a clear answer, but it's difficult to come out with a *good* answer without knowing much about your code. Thus I'm voting to close as unclear